# Detecting rapid increase in time series

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

I have a time series and I would like to detect when the values are increasing rapidly increasing and pinpoint (color perhaps) the timeframe of the increase. For example in the following plot I would like to pinpoint the spikes for a specific time window in x-axis (for example 2018-05-22)

[image]

I am able to find the 20% maximum values but that does not help me. I want to focus on the rapid increases instead.

```
d = pd.Series(df['TS'].values[1:] - df['TS].values[:-1], index=df['TS'].index[:-1]).abs()
threshold = 0.8
m = d.max()
print(d > m * threshold)
```

For example, ruptures is doing something similar visually. There is an example with random data along the plot it produces:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ruptures as rpt

# generate signal
n_samples, dim, sigma = 1000, 3, 4
n_bkps = 4  # number of breakpoints
#signal, bkps = rpt.pw_constant(n_samples, dim, n_bkps, noise_std=sigma)


# detection
algo = rpt.Pelt(model="rbf").fit(signal)
result = algo.predict(pen=10)

# display
rpt.display(signal, bkps, result)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You could calculate confidence intervals based on moving average and standard deviation and then mark the data points that are outside those. There was an article that did something similar, let me see if I find it. Edit: [check this](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-of-price-anomaly-detection-13586cd5ff46)

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look

Comment: Not quite what i am looking for unfortunately

Comment: A way to go here might be to smooth the data (e.g. with a Savitzky-Golay filter) and then analyze first (and second) derivative to determine a baseline. If you have the baseline identified, you can extract the signals. There might be other methods for baseline determination better suited for your specific type of measurement.

Comment: is your input data available somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try differencing the series to get the amount the series changed at each step. This is a standard method in time-series analysis. [Here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html) is a good discussion of the theory behind the idea.

In practice, `pandas` gives us a simple way to difference the series via the `.diff()` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
                   'b': [1, 1000, 20000, 3, 50, 80],
                   'c': [1000, 4, 97, 16, 2500, 36]})
df.diff()

      a        b       c
0   NaN      NaN     NaN
1  10.0    999.0  -996.0
2  10.0  19000.0    93.0
3  10.0 -19997.0   -81.0
4  10.0     47.0  2484.0
5  10.0     30.0 -2464.0
```

This process subtracts the next item in the series from the prior (which is why the first observation is now `NaN`). You can add a feature to your data that is the first-differenced series:

```
df['a_first_difference'] = df['a'].diff()
```

The values in this series then follow their own distribution. Perhaps finding all the values in the differenced series above some threshold would give you the way to measure "rapid increase" by identifying the periods that saw the biggest change over the previous value. It's also possible to get `.diff()` to tell you the change from the *next* value:

```
df.diff(periods=-1)

      a        b       c
0 -10.0   -999.0   996.0
1 -10.0 -19000.0   -93.0
2 -10.0  19997.0    81.0
3 -10.0    -47.0 -2484.0
4 -10.0    -30.0  2464.0
5   NaN      NaN     NaN
```

This, then, would help identify those periods when the next step experiences a large change.

Comment: I see. Thanks that really helped :)

Comment: You can also hit an upvote if you found the question useful. Thanks again :)